# my 'shopping cart' holds the item number how do i display the product name?

Tags: php, sql, database

im learning php here and have a basic shopping cart functioning, it shows me what item is in the cart when selected, but it only shows the value for 'productid' which is a 4 digit number i.e '0001'

i want it to show the item description too, my code is

```
<?php
   session_start();
$cart=$_SESSION["cart"];

   extract($_POST);
   if (IsSet($productid)||IsSet($_SESSION["notempty"])) $empty=false;
   else $empty=true;

   if (!$empty)
   {
      if (IsSet($cart[$productid])) $cart[$productid]+=$quantity;
      else $cart[$productid]=$quantity;
      $_SESSION["notempty"]=true;
   }

   $_SESSION["cart"]=$cart;
?>
```

the products are stored in a database too, the same ID would i need to call it from the database?

thanks

Ok so this is what i have now

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect({dbhost},{dbusername},{dbpassword},{dbname});
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT name, price FROM products = ".$var." WHERE productid = ".$i) ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['name'];
  echo $row['price'];
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

but i get an error on

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in .../cart.php on line 12

and

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../cart.php on line 54

what may i have done wrong?

thanks

Comment: why not store the product name in the session too, rather than have another database call when you want to display the cart?

Comment: the database is already active and used on other pages to display stock levels and such. i need to call the product name and price ideally from the id. so id '1' is 'thisproduct' with 'this price' and i want it to show this depending what products the customer has put in their basket.

Comment: its as if i need a basic select statement like on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp but with an if statement to say if the item no "0001' is in the session / been selected to display 'name' and 'price'

Comment: my point is why do another db query at all, you've presumably already pulled the information from the database on the page where the user adds the item to their basket, so just add the item name into the session at the same time you add the id?

Comment: no this hasnt been done, this was already made and the item name and price is there in the html text im going to use this calling function to display the product on those pages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to pass the product name along with the product id in the POST method or you need to run a SQL query when a product id exists and return the product name where the product id in the database table equals the product id you have in your cart.

Something similar to the below query can be used.

```
SELECT {product_name} FROM {product_table} WHERE id={product_id} LIMIT 1;
```

Updated Code Example:

```
$con = mysqli_connect({dbhost},{dbusername},{dbpassword},{dbname});
// Check connection

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, price FROM products WHERE productid = $i;") ;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['price'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: i understand all of that apart from LIMIT 1; does this mean it will only display 1 of the items?

Comment: Yes, LIMIT 1 means it will return only one entry, its just incase you have two products with the same ID in the database.

Comment: i tried using it with what i have now but cant get it to function i posted up the code which is giving me greif!

Comment: Have a look at my reply above, I've made a few changes to your code. Try this and let me know how you get on. Make sure you update your database details in the connection string, they've were removed for you own safety, its not advisable to put login details in a publicly viewable place. ;)

Comment: crap! totally forgot about that.. oops.. just tried it and get two errors

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/k0903037/www/cart.php on line 11 

which is the the while function 

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

and then 

    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/k0903037/www/cart.php on line 52

which is

  foreach ($cart as $id=>$no)

im guessing it doesnt like $cart and $result for some reason

Comment: Did you make sure that $i in the SQL statement is being set in your code as the product ID?

Comment: how do you mean? sorry im still learning.. the function shows $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, price FROM products WHERE productid = $i;") ;

Comment: $i needs to have the value of the product ID your looking to get the name of. For this example you can replace $i with the product ID to make sure your code is working but for a production sql query you'll need to assign the product id to the variable $i and put it into the SQL statement or just put the product ID directly into the SQL statement.

Comment: it works when i put the product in replacement with the $i i will try and use this its only 6 products but i just realised it populates every item every time. how do i assign the product id to the variable?